# Public/private knowledge in auctions

Tags: game-theory, auctions

1. Consider three firms that engage in a first-price auction. Firm $i$'s payoff when firm $j$ wins the auction is $S_{i,j}$, which is deterministic and publicly known.
2. The winning firm $i$ has to pay its bid and faces transaction costs $\tau_i+\epsilon_i$. $\tau_i$ is stochastic and has p.d.f. $g_i(\tau_i)$ with $E[\tau_i]=\hat{\tau}_i$; $\epsilon_i$ is stochastic and has p.d.f. $h_i(\epsilon_i)$ with $E[\epsilon_i]=\hat{\epsilon}_i$. (If it helps for tractability, we can assume that each player has the same distributions.)
3. When going into the auction, each firm $i$ knows the realization of its own $\tau_i$,  the distributions of $g_j(\tau_j)$, with $i\neq j$, of its competitors, and its own and others $h_k(\epsilon_k)$, with $k\in \{1,2,3\}$.

**Lemma:**
(a) There exists an unique bidding equilibrium $(b^*_1,b^*_2,b^*_3)$.

(b) Let $\pi_i$ be the expected profit of firm $i$ **prior to learning the realization** of its $\tau_i$

(i) $\frac{\partial \pi_i}{\partial \hat{\tau}_i}\leq 0$  (This is not as trivial as it seems because competing bidders may reduce their equilibrium bid in response.)

(ii) $\frac{\partial \pi_i}{\partial \hat{\tau}_{j}}\geq 0$, with $j\neq i$

Do you know a paper in which something like this treated? How can I prove this Lemma?

Particularly, part (b) seems super intuitive but I do not yet see how to proof it.

Comment: How is $S_{i,j}$ determined? Is it stochastic?

Comment: @WalrasianAuctioneer: This is finally deterministic and public information. Thanks for asking.